# How to tell when a QTMovie starts playing?

Tags: cocoa, quicktime, qtkit

So `QTMovie`s have `QTMovieDidEndNotification`, but no `QTMovieDidStartNotification`. How can I be notified when a `QTMovie` starts playing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering my own question: the `QTMovieRateDidChangeNotification` is activated when the movie starts to play. Of course the documentation doesn't actually document that. Bah.

Answer (score 3):

Start and pause are viewed by Quicktime as rate changes to 100% and 0% respectively. QTMovieRateDidChangeNotification is what you want, and check for the appropriate rate.